# How to reverse a string using explicit "slice of s from i to j with step k"?

Tags: python, string, slice, reverse, indices

I've seen that `::-1` can be used to reverse a string, but I thought it would be of interest to find the explicit integers `i:j:k` that would do the job.

I found the documentation [common-sequence-operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), but can't get it to work. This code test comes up short:

```
s = "abcd"
print(1,s[4:3:-1]) 
print(2,s[4:2:-1])    
print(3,s[4:1:-1])
print(4,s[4:0:-1])
print(5,s[4:-1:-1])
```

Here is the output:

```
1 
2 d
3 dc
4 dcb
5
```

It looks like you can't do this with an explicit formula, `s[i:j:k]`.

Usually I can figure out simple programming by trial-n-error, but that is not working here. Maybe a careful read of the documentation will get me over this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do it like this:

```
s = "abcd"
print(s[len(s):-len(s)-1:-1])
```

Or, as pointed out by [Terry Jan Reedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722804/terry-jan-reedy) in the comments, the following way of writing it illustrates nicely the length of the slice as `(stop - start) / step`:

```
print(s[-1:-1-len(s):-1])
```

The issue is that negative indexing starts at the back, so the negative indexes correspond the following "real" indexes:

```
-1 ->  3
-2 ->  2
-3 ->  1
-4 ->  0  # -len(s)
-5 -> -1  # that's the one you need (or any smaller number)
```

`0` or `-len(s)` is not enough since the `stop` index of the slice is exclusive, so you have to get one lower.

Comment: For that matter, any number less than `-len(s)` will work.

Comment: @glibdud Very true.

Comment: Yes, I'm not proud "monkey see monkey do" is easier than studying documentation!

Comment: s[-1:-len(s)-1:-1] works and is clearer to me as the bounds are len(s) apart.

Comment: It is clearer to me because the slice with these negative ints matches the arguments of an equivalent range: `list(range(-1, -5, -1)) == [-1, -2, -3, -4]`.  The same does not work for `list(range(3, -1, -1)) == [3, 2, 1, 0]`.